# Find $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, such that $f$ is continuous at $0$ and $f(2x)-f(x)=x^2$.

Tags: functions, continuity

Find $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, such that $f$ is continuous at $0$ and $f(2x)-f(x)=x^2$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Please read the FAQ that says that you should provide the context of your question, including any thoughts you've had on it. Otherwise it's unsuitable for this site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given $$f(2x)-f(x)=x^2$$
we can form 
$$f(x)-f(x/2)=\left(\frac{x}{2^1}\right)^2\\
f(x/2)-f(x/4)=\left(\frac{x}{2^2}\right)^2\\
.\\.\\.\\
f(x/2^{n-1})-f(x/2^n)=\left(\frac{x}{2^n}\right)^2$$

Adding above equations telescopically as $n\to\infty$ gives 
$$\begin{align}
f(x)&=f(0)+x^2\cdot\frac{(\frac{1}{2})^2}{1-(\frac{1}{2})^2}\\
&=\frac{1}{3}\cdot x^2 +f(0)
\end{align}$$

Comment: Use \left (, \right) for parenthese of the right size.

Comment: Do you even use that f is continuous in 0?

Comment: Yeah. If f wasn't continuous at 0 then the limits may not exist.

Comment: What limit? You used limit as n->infinity.

Comment: @OvyOvy As $n\to\infty$ the value $\frac{x}{2^n}\to0$. Given $f(0)$ is continuous it implies $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(\frac{x}{2^n})$ exists .

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Write $f(x)=f(x/2) + x^2/4$ and iterate: $f(x)=x^2(1/4+1/16) + f(x/4) =...=x^2/3 + \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} f(x/2^k) = x^2/3+c$ by continuity at 0 ($c=f(0)$ any real number).

Comment: Just when I wanted to post the same answer :)

Comment: Ahmmmm... How is it x^2/3?

Comment: do you even use that f is continuous in 0? cause if you do lim k->0 from f(x/2^k) you get f(x).

Comment: You are right. Misprint. The limit is when $k\rightarrow +\infty$. Corrected.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $f(x) = ax^2+bx+c$. Your condition requires
$$a(2x)^2+b(2x)+c-ax^2-bx-c=x^2$$
$$(3a-1)x^2+bx=0$$ for all $x$.
This happens if and only if both $3a-1=0$ and $b=0$, i.e., if $a=\frac13$ and $b=0$ (note $c$ is arbitrary). So any function of the form $$f(x) = \frac13x^2 + c$$ will do (of course, there may be others).

**Addendum:** If you suppose $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$, then the condition requires
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(2x)^n-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n = x^2$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(2^n-1)a_nx^n = x^2$$
$$0a_0 + a_1x + (3a_2-1)x^2 + \sum_{n=3}^{\infty}(2^n-1)a_nx^n = 0$$
This implies that $a_0$ may be chosen arbitrarily, that $a_1=0$, that $a_2=\frac13$, and that $(2^n-1)a_n=0$ for $n\geq 3$ (so $a_n=0$ for $n\geq 3$ since $2^n-1\neq 0$ for $n\geq 3$). So the only functions of this form are, as before, of the form $f(x) = \frac13x^2 + a_0$.

Comment: do you even use that f is continuous in 0?

Comment: No, but the functions I'm considering are all differentiable (so, continuous) at $x=0$. I'm not claiming that these are the *only* functions that will work, just that these are the only ones of this particular type. With them, you get continuity at $0$ for free.

Answer (score -1):

The solution i found is $$ f(x)=\frac{1}{3}x^2+c$$
i don't know if it's unique or not, tell me if you need more details.

**Explanation**:

I proceeded as follows:

First, i assumed that $f\in C^1(\mathbb{R})$ and that $f'$ is a linear function.

The first assumption is because i wanted to calculate the  derivative of the given equation.

Then, we obtain: $$2f'(2x)-f'(x)=2x $$
Using the linearity of $f'$ we write, $$2f'(2x)-\color{red}{\frac{1}{2}}f'(\color{red}2x)=2x $$
Thus,
$$\frac{3}{2}f'(2x)=2x $$
$$\int 2f'(2x)dx=\int \frac{8}{3}x dx$$
$$f(2x)=\frac{4}{3}x^2+c $$
$$ f(x)=\frac{1}{3}x^2+c$$
Where $c$ is a constant. And we clearly have the continuity of $f$ in $0$.

Comment: It would improve your Answer if an explanation of how you found the solution were included, e.g. variation of parameters or whatever can be articulated.

Comment: do you even use that f is continuous in 0?

Comment: no we don't have to use it to find the solution.
 the question states that the solution must be continuous in 0, so it is only a condition that needs to be verified in the function .

Answer (score -1):

f(2x) = f(x) + x^2

f(x) = f(x/2) + x^2/4

f(x) = f(x/4) + x^2/16 + x^2/4

```
  = f(x/8) + x^2/64 + x^2/16+ x^2/4
```

continuing like this

you will get

f(x) = f(x/2^k) + x^2 (1/4+ 1/4^2+......+ 1/4^k)

```
  = f(x/2^k) + x^2/3(1-(1/4)^k)
```

for some k ∈ N

k -> infinity

f(x) = f(0)+ x^2/3

Comment: Almost two years a member (!), it is loooong past time to learn how to properly write mathematics in this site, lest your post won't be even read by many...

Comment: do you even use that f is continuous in 0?